# Change UICollectionViewCell subview frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView subclass with several subviews. The cell class includes a method which should cause animation of one of the subviews within the cell (timerView). The problem is that although the NSLog() statements suggest that the frame is being changed, nothing happens. There is no change to the frame of the subview. How can I cause the frame of the subView to change?

```
UIView *superView = self.timerView.superview;

//Force the border view to layout so we can get the size
[superView layoutIfNeeded];

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(superView.frame));


self.timerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, superView.frame.size.height);

NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.timerView.frame));

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    self.timerView.frame = self.timerView.superview.frame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (completion) {
        completion();
    }
}];
```

Comment: Have you tried `reloadData`? why not `autolayout`?

Comment: I am using auto layout but I need to animate a change to the frame of one sub view in response to user interaction

Comment: I didn’t use reloadData because it will replace the cell with a new one rather than animating the change

Comment: Why not directly change the width constraint?

Comment: The view which is being animated is not using autolayout at this point, as manipulating the frame was an easy way to get it to animate. Do you think that would work where changing the frame didn't?

Comment: No, same problem I cannot even statically set an altered width constraint on the view programmatically when it is a subview of the collectionview cell

Comment: I deliberately made a demo, `UITableView` put a `UIButton`, a `UIView`, I use the click event to change the `UIView` frame is working, you provide more information, the main thread considered?

Comment: I'm not using a tableView, I'm using a collectionView. The code I posted above is triggered by the user selecting something outside of the collectionView cell and should cause animation to occur within the cell. But it doesn't work. No visual properties of the cell seem to be changeable other than when the user interacts with the cell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201421/discussion-between-nullable-and-mashers).

Comment: How is `timerView` added to `UICollectionViewCell`, whether it is `frame` or `autolayout`, I am trying to write a demo to verify

Comment: I have tried it both ways, frame and autolayout. It is added as a subview of the cell by the cell itself

Comment: Is this part of the animation code in the cell? If you add `UICollectionViewCell` via `autolayout`, you should use `autolayout` to change the constraint. Similarly, if you add it with `frame`, you can change it with `frame`. what is the property modification of `timerView`?

Comment: Yes the animation code is in the cell. And as I said, I have tried it with autolayout and a frame, but neither worked. `timerView` is just alloced and inited, and given a background colour

Comment: The last question, how do you get the cell? How to trigger an animation?

Comment: When the cell is selected, a reference is stored and a popup menu presented. Then when the option in the popup menu is selected which should start the animation, the reference to the cell is used and a method called on it to start the animation

Comment: I am very sorry, I think your question should be that a certain detail is missing. I have not found it yet. Check if the animation is in the main thread? Is the `timerView` object released in the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urgh, the answer was so simple but it took me hours to work it out. I was retrieving the reference to the target `UICollectionViewCell` in  `collectionView: didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`, using `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. This meant that the cell which was being referenced was not always the cell I thought it was, because of dequeueing. In the end I created a custom delegate callback from the cell so I could have my own `didSelectItem...` method, which also passed the cell itself. That way I knew that the cell I was addressing would always be the one I thought it was, and the animation then started working.

I only realised this when I started having problems with properties I knew I had set becoming `nil` when accessed from other methods. So I realised a new cell was being dequeued.

Thanks for all the help, and sorry it was a bit of a wild goose chase.